# Keep x number of files and delete all others - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a script that will look through a set of folders and keep only the last 10 files. The files in each folder could be created daily, weekly or monthly. I need the script to keep the 10 most recent copies regardless of the creation date or modified date.

Using another post I created the script below that works but it doesnt keep 10 copies it keeps any file that isn't older than 10 days.

```
$ftppath = "C:\Reports"
Get-ChildItem $ftppath -recurse *_Report_*.zip -force|where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-10)} |Remove-Item -force
```

Any idea on how I can tweak this to work? If I use the script below it works but only if I dont set -Recurse. If you use the -Recurse switch you get an error that I have listed below the script.

```
# Keeps latest 10 files from a directory based on Creation Time

#Declaration variables
$path = "C:\Reports"                               # For example $path= C:\log\*.tmp
$total= (ls $path).count - 10 # Change number 5 to whatever number of objects you want to keep
# Script
ls $path |sort-object -Property {$_.CreationTime} | Select-Object -first $total | Remove-Item -force
```

> Error: Select-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'First'.
>   The -7 argument is less than the minimum allowed range of 0. Supply an
>   argument that is greater than 0 and then try the command again.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can sort by `CreationTime` descending and skip the first 10. If there are less than 10 files it will not remove any.

```
gci C:\temp\ -Recurse| where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc| 
    select -Skip 10| Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Ah `-Skip`. Nice and concise :-) +1

Comment: Was testing this and got some odd results, not sure what was going on there... Re-tested and it's working as I'd expect. Nice 1 liner.

Comment: @Andy - yeah, I tried your code to create files,  and the second time I ran it, The creationTime didn't get updated for all the files. I don't know exactly why though :-/

Comment: I feel like this is a better solution than the accepted. Learned about `-Skip`. +1

Comment: Use LastWriteTime instead of CreationTime. I did the following: create a backup zip, then copy some junk files in that directory to get over 10 files for testing. When I ran the script, the backup zip was deleted because the creation time of the junk files was newer. LastWriteTime is the time the file was last modified (i.e., actual creation time), not when it was copied.

Answer (score 8):

**Updated**

```
$path = "C:\TestDir"

# Create 12 test files, 1 second after each other
1..12 | % {
    Remove-Item -Path "$path\$_.txt" -ea SilentlyContinue
    $_ | Out-File "$path\$_.txt"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
$keep = 10
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
    $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to `Remove-Item` when your ready to delete for real.

Comment: Doesn't this remove all files?

Comment: Ah thanks yep the old version would of. Helps to test more ;-) I updated with a tested working version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is now running as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

@Andy: My rep is too low to comment so posting an answer. If you are getting strange results, it may be because you are looking in Windows Explorer which by default shows the Last Modified date instead of the Creation Date. To get results consistent with that shown in Windows Explorer, swap LastWriteTime for CreationTime like so: 
    gci C:\temp\ -Recurse| where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort LastWriteTime -desc
    | select -Skip 10| Remove-Item -Force

Answer (score -2):

How to call this GCI command in SQL server , was trying below code but returning error

```
declare @deleteoldtempxe nvarchar(1000)
        set @deleteoldtempxe='powershell.exe gci '+''''+ 'I:\New folder\'+''''+' -Recurse| where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc| 
    select -Skip 1| Remove-Item -Force'
    select @deleteoldtempxe

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @deleteoldtempxe
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you have further questions, please add them as a comment to the original question or one of the answers. Please do not write an answer which actually does not answer the question.