# Powershell Script or Batch file to Only keep the 4 most recent files in each subdirectory

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need help developing a script to do the following.

I have my recorded Tv .WTV files in subdirectories in my c:\recorded tv folder.
for example:
c:\recorded tv\blacklist\
c:\recorded tv\batman\
etc

I would like a script that I can schedule, via the task scheduler, that would delete the older wtv files in there respective subdirectory and only keep the 4 most recent wtv files in their respective subdirectory based on recorded date.

Is that possible?

Comment: thanks but not the same as the other posts.

Comment: The logic in the linked post is what you are looking for. you just need to apply it in a foreach loop so that it works for each sub-directory. If you are having trouble with that update your post with what you have done and we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted the solution below based on similar SO post at [Keep x number of files and delete all others - Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810580/keep-x-number-of-files-and-delete-all-others-powershell)

```
$path = "c:\recorded tv"
$keep = 4

$subdirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select-object FullName
foreach ($dir in $subdirs) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | ?{-not $_.PsIsContainer}
    if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
        $files | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) | Remove-Item -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.  unfortunately that other post, does solve the issues.  I need to only keep the 4 most recent files for EACH subdirectory. The other post took all the files in the subdirectory and only kept the most recent 10 files.

Comment: Jason, there is not need to make an answer. You have already flagged this post.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I am still learning the SO conventions...

Comment: Mickey - I have edited the answer to adapt the other post to your scenario. Hopefully that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For a batch solution

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=c:\recorded tv"
    set "fileType=.wtv"
    set "keep=4"

    for /d %%d in ("%root%\*") do for /f "skip=%keep% delims=" %%a in (
        'dir /b /o-d /a-d "%%~fd\*%fileType%"'
    ) do echo del "%%~fd\%%~a"
```

The code executes two `for` loops:

- `for %%d` enumerates the folders under the indicated root.
- `for %%a` executes a `dir` command over the folder being processed, retrieving the list of files inside it in reverse date order. The top n files are skipped (the newer files) and for the rest of the files, a `del` command is executed.

File removal operations are only echoed to console, if the output is correct, remove the `echo` command that prefixes `del`