# Keep X folders in a directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm working on keeping a archive directory of folders. Each folder contains multiple files representing a backup of an application instance for the day and the folder is created (and named) based on the day the backup was created. I want to keep X folders available at a given time and delete the older folders.

I attempted to implement a solution based on this [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810580/keep-x-number-of-files-and-delete-all-others-powershell).

My new code is as follows:

```
gci E:\sql_backups\Everything\Archive -Recurse|where {-not $_PsIsContainer}|sort CreationTime -desc| select -Skip X| Remove-Item -Force
```

There are two issues I'm running into. The first is that when the script is run it will still prompt for the recursion [UI prompt for recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKydV.png).

The second issue is that it is now removing all folders from the directory, regardless of the value of X.

Comment: You’re missing a period for one $_.psiscontainer

Comment: @DougMaurer Thanks. That fixes the recursion prompt, but now the code is just leaving one item in each child folder.

Comment: Shouldn’t you add -recurse to remove-item?

Comment: Based on example 4 in the MS documentation the top level -recurse should be okay since I'm wrapping in a GCI. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7

Comment: Your command will only produce files since you are filtering with `-not $_.psiscontainer` so you're only going to be removing files in the current code,not folders.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are strictly returning files, you will have to do a little more work. As I commented, you are missing a period in `$_.PsIsContainer`. This should achieve your desired result.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\sql_backups\Everything\Archive -Recurse |
    Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}| Sort-Object CreationTime -desc |
        Select-Object -Skip X | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.PSParentPath -Recurse -Force}
```

Also, in powershell version 3.0 and up there exist `-File` and `-Directory` parameters so you can replace your where clause with `-File`

```
Get-ChildItem E:\sql_backups\Everything\Archive -Recurse -File |
    Sort-Object CreationTime -desc | Select-Object -Skip X |
        Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.PSParentPath -Recurse -Force}
```

Comment: The top solution ended up wiping all of my folders. I changed the {-not $_.PSISContainer} and to just {$_.PSIsContainer} at which point the Foreach-Object wasn't really necessary and I could just use a Remove-Item

Comment: Sweet, add your answer and accept it tomorrow if it is good

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this to solve the problem.

```
gci E:\sql_backups\Everything\Archive -Recurse|where {$_.PsIsContainer}|sort CreationTime -desc| select -Skip X| Remove-Item -recurs-force
```

Looking at it, it will likely have issues with folders created at the same time (arbitrarily choosing which to remove), but given I'm doing daily folder creation this seems acceptable for my needs.